# CAST Correct VARCHAR to DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

Good Day

I am working of a existing SQL Server Database. What the developers did is to keep the Date and time separate. The Date is in DateTime format (what I want) but the time is incorrect. if it is 14:30 it shows as 1430 when its 09:25 shows as 925. I am trying tyo combine the date and time to have a Date Time view for an program I am writing on top of this database.

I have created the date as a normal date like this:

```
CASE 
   WHEN LEN(T0.BeginTime) = 3 THEN '0' + LEFT(T0.BeginTime, 1) + ':' + RIGHT(T0.BeginTime, 2) 
   ELSE LEFT(T0.BeginTime, 2) + ':' + RIGHT(T0.BeginTime, 2) 
END AS 'NEW Start Time'`
```

The date now looks like it's the correct format but when I want to combine the date and time I get `VARCHAR` to `DateTime` error.

How can I fix this?

This is the error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value (ONLY RAN 804 RECORDS)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different approach is to convert the time column in minutes and add it to the date

```
DATEADD(minute, T0.BeginTime / 100 * 60 + T0.BeginTime % 100
              , CONVERT(VARCHAR, T0.BeginDate, 112))
```

with that the length of the time column doesn't matter

Comment: T0.BeginTime is `VARCHAR` so you would need to cast it.

Comment: @GiannisParaskevopoulos if the content is only numeric SQLServer implicitly convert it

Comment: `00:08` is a possible value.

Comment: @GiannisParaskevopoulos in the comment to your answer the OP says that  if the time is `00:08` it will show as `8` in the field, not that `00:08` is a possible value

Comment: @Serpiton i think there is a flaw, I tried converting '1430' and its giving me a out-of-range error, please see my solution below.

Comment: @GouriShankarAechoor I tried it in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/37515) and I don't see any error

Comment: @Serpiton you are right my example was wrong, apologies. However you may want to add negative logic, please see below for examples.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, Hope it helps.

```
DECLARE @DateTime TABLE (
DateWithTime DATE,
BeginTime INT);

INSERT INTO  @DateTime
VALUES  ('2014-08-04', '1525'),
       ('2014-08-04', '525'),
       ('2014-08-04', '15'),
       ('2014-08-04', '5'),
       ('2014-08-04', '0'),
       ('2014-08-04', '90')

;WITH cte_BeginTimeFix
AS (
SELECT
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateWithTime, 120) AS DateWithTime,
RIGHT('0000' + CAST(BeginTime AS VARCHAR(4)), 4) AS BeginTime
FROM @DateTime
)
, cte_DateString
AS (
SELECT  DateWithTime,
      BeginTime,
      DateWithTime + ' ' + STUFF(STUFF('00:00:00.000', 4, 2, RIGHT(BeginTime, 2)), 1, 2, LEFT(BeginTime, 2)) AS DateTimeStr
FROM cte_BeginTimeFix
)
SELECT DateWithTime,
     BeginTime,
     CASE
     WHEN ISDATE(DateTimeStr) = 1 THEN CAST(DateTimeStr AS DATETIME)
     ELSE NULL
     END AS DateTimeStr
FROM cte_DateString
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
CONVERT
(
    DATETIME,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,T0.Date,112) + 
    ' ' + 
    CASE 
        WHEN ISNULL(T0.BeginTime,'0') = '0'
        THEN '00:00'
        ELSE
            RIGHT
            (
                '00' + LEFT(T0.BeginTime,LEN(T0.BeginTime) - 3),
                2
            ) + 
            ':' + 
            RIGHT(T0.BeginTime,2)
    END        
)
```

Comment: Hi This is much closer then what I had before. It gets to around 14848 records and then error: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or Substring Function.

Comment: Just had a look at the very next record and the time that they selected was 00:00 - Any ideas what to do with a record that is NULL? In SQL it's = 0

Comment: What was Null? Can you share the values of that row?

Comment: Sorry - In SQL the TIME = 0, Not 000 just 0

Comment: Ok, this is getting complex, but my edit should work.

Comment: That sorted out that issue. What I do notice is that when the time is 00:# it shows only the minutes i.e it now stopped at record 27043 because 27044 is 00:08 and the time shows as 8 only. That means that the LENGTH can also be 1. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Though you have already selected an answer, it would be nice if you would try my edit.

Comment: The new edit stops on record 799, the next record is 18 only i.e the selected time was 00:18.